# Catalog view template to handle product with custom option

Tags: product, magento-1.9, template, custom-options

Looking for disabling select dropdown on product detail page for simple product with custom options. & Would like instead using onclick swatches (tiny images or links) which behave in same way, on select works.

Here is the snapshot for what i want to express:

[image]

Which template view should i edit to achieve this?

P.S. none of the product type (simple, grouped or confiurable) exist in my theme 
[frontend/default/galayomarket/template/catalog/product/view directory  ]

Answer (score 1):

Please enable template path hint you will find the exact file location of that thing.

To Enable template path hint follow below steps.

**Step 1 :** Open your Magento admin panel dashboard.

**Step 2 :** Now go to the System menu >> Configuration. Click on that.
[image: magento Admin Panel]

**Step 3 :** Then go to Developer section and  look at debug section as below.

**Step 4 :** Now you can see that here is not any option regarding "**Template Path Hints**". For that you have to change the **Current Configuration Scope** of your site .

Go to the left end side and  you see on dropdown and then change as per below.

[image: Current Configuration Scope]

**Step 5 :** The page is reload automatically when you click on that once. and you see the below page. Select the Yes and click on **save config button.** Go to your front side and you can see the **Template Path Hints.**

[image: Template Path Hints]